# How to change popupwindow z-index android

Tags: java, android

I can open several [popupWindows](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) in my activity and change position by dragging them. The last opened popupWindows always is on top. How I can change order of popupWindows. For example show second one on top order when touch it. 
[image]